# Can't see the ads on my Windows 8 app (Microsoft Advertising SDK)

Tags: html, windows-8, windows-store-apps, ads

I developed two windows 8 application, I published them to the store, On Pub Center I created two applications and some ads units,

All Ads units are displayed on the first one, and not on the second application (same configuration).

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to check the **Internet Client** on  the **Capabilities tab** in  **package.appxmanifest** file.